# Display web page in each pc different

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have made a simple web page using jQuery. When opening it on another PC, it seems different (bigger and some of HTML table overflows from from the body tabs).

Can you tell me why its happen? How can I make this display the same on all machines?

My css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  label { width: 15em; float: left; }
  label.error { display: none; float: none; color: red;
                 padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
  p { clear: both; }
  .submit { margin-left: 12em; }
  em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family:Times new roman, verdana;
    font-size:22px;
    width: 950px;
    height:70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    background-image:url("wood_texture2.jpg");
    overflow:auto;
  }
</style>
```

My PC is oblong about 15 inches and the others is square about 14 inches.

Comment: Can you post some example code please ? It might be because you're specifying width in percentages and the other PC has a higher resolution, but it's hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: You might want to indicate what environmental differences may exist.. what browser does each PC use? What version of that browser? Are they all PC, or a mix of PCs, Macs and iPads?

Comment: my PC use linux and another ones is windows.but same brand (DELL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one thing you aren't considering is resolution.  If my computer uses a different DPI resolution as yours, even with the same size monitor it will appear bigger or smaller.

Other reasons why this could happen, the browser settings could have different minimum font sizes.  The browsers could accidentally be stuck in 'zoom' mode.

You could be using different browsers.

You could have different fonts installed.

in windows you could be using a large DPI which makes everything appear bigger.

There are a lot of factors why they could appear different.

Comment: yah..different browser different result..in google chrome no problem. but in mozilla firefox 3.6 appear bigger.

Comment: Try resetting the zoom in firefox via _V_iew->Zoom->Reset.  And try resetting the browser settings, or checking the minimum font size allowed